# Australian Government Locator Service (AGLS) Metadata - Is it widely adopted?

Tags: meta-tags

Recently, I have seen in a couple sites around Australia's meta data AGLS tags.

```
<meta name="AGLS.Audience" scheme="agls-audience" content="All"/>
<meta name="DC.Publisher" scheme="AglsAgent" content="Hyundai"/>
```

I have never seen this kind of mark-up before and discovered:
http://www.agls.gov.au/

Just wondering whether there is a big community / support out there for the adopting these tags? Any thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Government_Locator_Service) AGLS is "used by government agencies throughout Australia to classify electronic and physical services that are provided by the Australian government."

- The Australian government AGLS website has the documentation including a [PDF Guide](http://www.agls.gov.au/pdf/Guide%20to%20expressing%20AGLS%20metadata%20in%20XML%20v1.0.PDF)
- [The Drupal CMS has a plugin for supporting AGLS](https://drupal.org/project/agls)
- Some Australian universities have adopted for some data published on their websites.

Beyond that, it doesn't appear to enjoy widespread support, especially outside of Australia.